# jQuery Scrollify - first section ignores offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-scrollify

First time using jquery-scrollify. I have a page with a border around it and each section is meant to start 24px from top of page so it starts below the border. Without scrollify my CSS does this fine. Once I implement scrollify, even with the correct offset option, the page is always scrolled so that the top of this first section is right at the top of the page. Once I start scrolling to lower sections, they are respecting the offset and aligning properly. It seems the offset options is ignored for the first section? Is there any way to make the offset apply to the first section / start of page?

HTML

```
<section class="hero-home">
  <div class="slide" style="background-image: url('/img/hero-home1.jpg')"></div>
  <div class="slide" style="background-image: url('/img/hero-home2.jpg')"></div>
  <div class="slide" style="background-image: url('/img/hero-home3.jpg')"></div>
  <div class="slide" style="background-image: url('/img/hero-home4.jpg')"></div>
</section>
```

JS

```
var scrollOffset = -24;

$.scrollify({
  section: ".slide:visible",
  offset: scrollOffset,
  easing: "easeOutQuint",
  scrollSpeed: 800,
  scrollbars: true,
  setHeights: false,
  updateHash: false,
  touchScroll: true
});
```

The -24 offset is to account for a fixed position frame I have at top of the page. When a new "section" is scrolled to the top, it should stop 24px from top of page rather than right at the top, otherwise it goes under the frame.

The first "section" starts in the right place before I initiate scrollify (my CSS on a containing element has top padding equal to height of the frame). However once scrollify is added, the page is scrolled down 24px so that the first "section" appears right at the top of page. The "offset" options corrects this on all subsequent sections (2nd, 3rd, and 4th section appear at the right place when I scroll down) but the 1st section's initial position is incorrect and ignores the offset option value.

Comment: Show us some markup and code. See [mcve] in the help center.

Comment: Question edited to add more detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this issue as well, to fix this issue you want to provide some handling in the before event.

Solution Example

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.scrollify({
    section : ".fp-section",
    offset:-200,
    setHeights:false,

//Add the offset for the first element here:
//snapToElm is the list of element pages

    before:function(indexPosition,snapToElm){
        if(indexPosition===0){
            snapToElm[0].css({"margin-top":"200px"});
        }
        if(indexPosition>0){
            snapToElm[0].css({"margin-top":"0"});
        }
    },


    afterRender:function(){

     //set the first element initially to the desired offset
      $($(this.section)[0]).css({"margin-top":"200px"});
     //  stuff to do once scrollify has rendered the list
    }

})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.scrollify({
        section: "section",
        interstitialSection: ".fourth-view,footer",
        easing: "easeOutExpo",
        scrollSpeed: 1100,
        offset:0,
        scrollbars: true,
        standardScrollElements: "",
        setHeights: false,
        overflowScroll: true,
        updateHash: false,
        touchScroll: true,
        before: function () {
        },
        after: function () {
        },
        afterResize: function () {
        },
        afterRender: function () {
        }
    });
    if ($.scrollify.current().hasClass('second-view')) {
        $.scrollify.setOptions({offset: 0})
    }
    else {
        $.scrollify.setOptions({offset: -64.5})
    }
```

and also

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
if ($.scrollify.current().hasClass('second-view')) {
    $.scrollify.setOptions({offset: 0})
}
else {
    $.scrollify.setOptions({offset: -64.5})
}
```

});

remove offset for second section

Answer (score 0):

Change the source code line 660 of jquery.scrollify.js

```
if(i>0) {
heights[i] = parseInt($this.offset().top) + settings.offset;
} else {
  heights[i] = parseInt($this.offset().top);
}
```

Change to

```
heights[i] = parseInt($this.offset().top) + settings.offset;
```

- The version of jQuery Scrollify is 1.0.20

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution below but finally I just added the "section / slide class" to my header or navbar (`<header class="slide navbar otherclasses..."></header>`) that make my navbar the first element, it may not fit anyone but in my case its by far the most confortable for my users.

Edit : you need to set `setHeights: false` otherwise its not going to work well.